# Pre get posts for single post

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination, pre-get-posts, single

I pre get posts for a events archive page:
http://www.netzwerk-leipziger-freiheit.de/veranstaltungen/

```
function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
// do not modify queries in the admin
    if( is_admin()  ){  
    return $query;
}

// only modify queries for 'event' post type
if( isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'events' ) {
    $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');   
    $query->set('meta_key', 'vdatum');   
    $query->set('order', 'ASC');
}

   // return
    return $query;
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');
```

This will all work but if you select a single event the order is not depend on the pre get post query. And when you go to the last event on the left button on an event it ends in a 404.

I will be happy for any solution.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `$query` object is passed by reference, you don't need to return `$query` in `pre_get_posts`.

Second, `is_post_type_archive( 'events' )` will work just fine, you don't need to use `query->query_vars[]`.

Corrected code will look like this:

```
function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

    if( ! is_admin() && is_main_query() && is_post_type_archive( 'events' ) ) {
        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');   
        $query->set('meta_key', 'vdatum');   
        $query->set('order', 'ASC');
    }

}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');
```

Third, this action will probably not work in your case as you output the links to prev and next posts differently. In `pre_get_posts` you can set new arguments for the main `WP_Query`, but it will not work for other functions, like `get_next_post()`, `get_previous_post()`, `get_adjacent_post()`.

However, those functions use filter `get_{$adjacent}_post_sort`, with default value of `"ORDER BY p.post_date $order LIMIT 1"`. You can try using this filter in combination with `get_{$adjacent}_post_join` to add your meta query.

See "Filters" sections [on this page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post#Filters).

Comment: When i use this code the main nav will disappear.

Comment: It shouldn't. This code does not interfere with navigation, it is applied only to main query outside of admin, and only on 'events' post type archive. Probably, you have an error in your code somewhere else.